# Как можно оптимизировать задачу?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, олимпиада

> ### Носки
>
> Имеется стол длины L. На столе разложено N носков так, что никакой
> носок не вылезает за границы стола. Далее имеется умный мальчик Вася,
> который хочет (сугубо в корыстных целях) замерить толщину покрытия
> стола носками в M точках. Конец носка также накрывает точку стола, в
> которой он находится.
>
> #### Входные данные
>
> В первой строке заданы L,N,M(1≤L≤10000,1≤N≤10000,1≤M≤100000).
>
> Далее идут N пар чисел l≤r от 1 до L — левые и правые концы носков,
> каждая в отдельной строке.
>
> Затем идут M чисел от 1 до L — интересующие Васю точки, каждое в
> отдельной строке.
>
> Все числа целые.
>
> #### Выходные данные
>
> Выведите M чисел — толщину носкового покрытия в каждой точке.

Примеры

```
Ввод
31 12 4

19 20
1 3
9 26
8 31
15 26
15 20
5 20
17 27
21 23
2 24
10 19
1 27

15
23
28

Вывод 8
7
1
7
```

С задачей я разобрался , но как придумать эффективное решение?
Данный код не проходит по времени

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()

 {

    int l;

    cin >> l;
    int n;

    cin >> n;
    int m;

    cin >> m;
    vector<int> a (n);
    vector<int> b(n);
    vector<int> c(m);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n;i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        cin >> b[i];

    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < m;i++) {
        cin >> c[i];

    }


for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n;i++) {
        if (a[i] <= c[j] && c[j] <= b[i]) {
            ans++;

        }

    }

       cout << ans <<  endl;
}



}
```

Comment: Стол = прямая линия. Носки = лежащие на ней отрезки. По координате точки нужно выводить, сколько отрезков ее касаются.

Comment: Ааа , точно , не представляю , как я мог этого не заметить, в общем, СПАСИБО

Comment: А как можно ускорить программу ? Просто в лоб не принимает

Comment: А вы покажите свое решение "в лоб".

Comment: Вот , добавил моё решение , буду очень благодарен за подсказку

Comment: Мой ответ не реализовали?

Comment: Да суть-то простая - начался носок - толщина прибавилась на 1,  а кончился - убавилась на 1.

Comment: Дошло, спасибо вам за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте общий массив/вектор, содержащий пары `(координата; признак -1/0/+1)`. Признак -1 соответствует концу носка, +1 - началу носка, 0 - "интересующая точка".

Отсортируйте массив по координате. При равенстве координат +1 идёт раньше (чтобы учесть `Конец носка также накрывает точку стола, в которой он находится`)

Вначале `покрытие = 0`. Пройдите по массиву, добавляя значение признака к покрытию. Если признак=0 - выведите текущее значение покрытия.

Пример на Python

```
lf = [2, 4, 6, 7] # левые концы
rt = [8, 7, 7, 9] # правые концы
chk = [1, 5, 6, 7, 9]  # точки проверки
pt = []
for x in lf:
    pt.append((x, 1))
for x in rt:
    pt.append((x, -1))
for x in chk:
    pt.append((x, 0))
pt.sort(key=lambda point: (point[0], -point[1]))
print(pt)
coverage = 0
for x in pt:
    if x[1] == 0:
        print(x[0], coverage)
    coverage += x[1]

[(1, 0), (2, 1), (4, 1), (5, 0), (6, 1), (6, 0), 
 (7, 1), (7, 0), (7, -1), (7, -1), (8, -1), (9, 0), (9, -1)]
1 0
5 2
6 3
7 4
9 1
```