# Пожалуйста помогите улучшить решение задачи

Tags: python, олимпиада

Я уже написал код на phyton, но он не до конца работает. Помогите пожалуйста

Задача:

Условие
n строителей несут одну балку. И вдруг перед ними оказываются
k ям. Строители, не долго думая, двинулись прямиком через эти ямы.
Если вдруг один человек оказался над ямой, то он немедленно вцепляется в балку, а остальные продолжают идти, и таким образом строители пытаются преодолеть ямы.Но строители не всемогущи, поэтому если в какой-то момент суммарный вес строителей, находящихся над пропастью, превышает суммарный вес строителей, стоящих на земле, то у остальных не хватает сил выдержать висящих на балке, и те падают в яму.
Благо яма не глубокая, поэтому все отделаются легким испугом.
Когда хотя бы один человек падает, все остальные прекращают движение, и ваше наблюдение заканчивается.

Формат входных данных
Первая строка входного файла содержит два числа: n количество строителей, k количество ям.
Вторая строка список координат относительно начала балки строителей и их веса: p1, w1, ..., pn, wn. Координаты рабочих считаются от левого конца балка
Третья строка координаты краёв ям: l1, r1, ..., lk, rk.

Формат выходных данных
Выходной файл должен содержать одно число - количество упавших строителей

Стандартный вход:

```
3 1
0 1 1 1 2 1
1 1
```

Стандартный выход:

```
0
```

Я уже написал код, который проходит по нескольким тестам, но возникают ошибки в других тестах

вот код на python:

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
builders = list(map(int, input().split()))
holes = list(map(int, input().split()))

fallen_count = 0
total_weight = 0
max_weight = 0
i = 0
p=0
sch = 1
all_w = 0

for j in range(n):
    all_w = all_w + builders[sch]
    sch += 2
count = 0
for j in range(n):
    if holes[i] <= builders[p] <= holes[i+1] and builders[p+1]>(all_w-builders[p+1]):
        count += 1
    p += 2

print(count)
```

Очень надеюсь на помощь
Заранее спасибо

PS
Ограничения

```
0<N∗K≤10**6
0<li,ri≤10**9
0<pi,<pi+1≤10**9
1<∑wi≤10**9
```

Comment: Что делает ваш код? Как вы решаете задачу?

Comment: Какие ограничения на n и k?

Comment: Первой строчкой я ввожу кол-во строителей(n) и ям(k). Во второй строчке вводится n*2 чисел, нечётные - координата строителя, а чётные - вес строителя. В третей строчке вводятся координаты краёв ямы. Затем задаются необходимые переменные. Далее с помощью цикла считается общий вес строителей. Потом в цикле задаётся условие при котором строитель падает в яму и считается кол-во упавших строителей. Последней строчкой выводится число упавших строителей.

Comment: добавил ограничения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ограничение `0<N∗K≤10**6` облегчает задачу.
Пусть условная скорость движения 1 метр в секунду.
Сгенерируем все события для каждого строителя

```
for i in range(n):
    delta = builder[-1].pos-builder[i].pos
    for j in range(k):
        events.append((delta + hole[j].start, -1, builder[i].weight))
        events.append((delta + hole[j].end, 1, builder[i].weight))
```

Отсортируем события по времени - первому элементу кортежа, а при равенстве учтём второй элемент (это будет применено автоматически).

Пройдём по списку событий. На каждом шаге отнимаем от количества висящих значение `tuple[1]`, а от веса  висящих значение `tuple[1]*tuple[2]`. Если оно превысило половину общего веса - упали. Количество в это момент известно.

Как это работает:

При движении i-й строитель встречает начало или конец ямы с позицией `pos`  в момент времени `delta+pos` (delta - сколько он сначала прошёл до старта)

Вот все эти события для всех людей и краёв ям заранее генерируем и записываем в events в виде кортежа - время, +/-1 - признак начала или конца ямы, вес строителя.

После сортировки мы имеем правильную последовательность событий во времени.

Когда мы встречаем событие с признаком -1, то человек повисает, его вес добавляется к висячим.  Когда мы встречаем событие с признаком +1, то человек выходит из ямы, его вес убирается из общего веса висящих.

Вот пара подобных задач:

[Как можно оптимизировать задачу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132573/)
[Python, задание найти пересечения времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257076/)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Если не затруднит, не могли бы вы отправить как будет выглядеть полный код?

Comment: Вы же олимпиадник, зачем вам полный код?  Псевдокод основной части я дал, остальное несложно. Если не всё понятно - спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо вам ещё раз

Comment: Я всё равно не совсем понимаю ваше решение

Comment: Задача решена с помощью заметания. На пальцах объяснить не получится. Надо решить десяток задач, потратить неделю. Потом можно будет вернуться и удивиться простоте решения.

Comment: Хорошо, посижу над решением с пачкой листов и карандашом

Comment: Добавил пояснения